# Does reducing desired instances in (AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup) terminates the instance without stopping it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I have created a custom AMI wherein a service xxx is started when aws instance gets started and service xxx gets stopped when that aws instance gets stopped.
I have wrapped that ami under CloudFormation's AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup.
When a new instance gets added using auto scaling group the xxx service too gets started on it. But when I reduce the number of desired instances the xxx does not get stopped.

So reducing desired numInstances in autoscaling group simply terminates the instance without stopping it?

How do I get the notification to stop the xxx service before instance termination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when Auto Scaling scales down/in, it terminates instances (it does not simply stop them).

To react to such an event, you can use [Lifecycle Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) which allow you to perform custom actions as Auto Scaling  launches or terminates instances.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, Any example of using Lifecycle Hooks in cloudformation template would be useful...

Comment: One example here: https://engineering.circle.com/the-hook-the-message-and-the-function-16e7df31666c

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, for AWS::Lambda::Function what all "Runtime" are supported like python, shell script? etc..

Comment: The AWS::Lambda::Function documentation is helpful here. For valid values, see the Runtime property in the AWS Lambda Developer Guide (which is at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateFunction.html#SSS-CreateFunction-request-Runtime).